# What's the difference between variable definition and declaration in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is this a variable **definition** or **declaration**? And why?

`var x;`

..and is the memory reserved for x after this statement?

EDIT:
In C extern `int x;` is a declaration, `int x = 5;` is a definition. What's the analog in JS? Wikipedia says a declaration allocates memory and the definition assigns a value to this allocated memory.

SECOND EDIT: 
I think the explanation of @Deryck sounds great, but there's some output that disagrees with his explanation:

```
> var x;
undefined
> x
undefined // now it looks like x is defined to the value undefined
> y
ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

If the `ReferenceError` output would say `y is not declared` it would make sense. But often I read that JS has two non-values: `null` and `undefined`. So `var x` would be a definition with the value `undefined`.

Comment: what are the important distinctions for you between the words "definition" and "declaration"?

Comment: ES5 talks about `var` *declaring* variables: http://es5.github.io/#x12.2

Comment: The concept of "memory" in JavaScript is much more abstract than it is in some other languages, like C and C++.

Comment: thanks @Pointy so does this statement reserve memory or not?

Comment: @cakl well in JavaScript it's not really defined behavior. It declares a symbol in the local scope. Whether there's memory allocated or not is up to the runtime system.

Comment: @cakl Why are you worried about memory allocation? In JavaScript memory is dynamically allocated and automatically garbage collected. There are no pointers, malloc, etc in JavaScript.

Comment: @Cuberto I'm not worried about this. I just wanted to know if you can make a clear difference between declaration and definition in javascript as you can do this in c/c++.

Answer (score 28):

`var x` is a **declaration** because you are not **defining** what value it holds but you are **declaring** its existence and the need for memory allocation.

`var x = 1` is both declaration and definition but are separated with `x` being **declared** in the beginning while its **definition** comes at the line specified (variable assignments happen inline).

I see that you already understand the concept of `hoisting` but for those that don't, Javascript takes every variable and function declaration and brings it to the top (of its corresponding scope) then trickles down assigning them in order.

You seem to know most of this already though.  Here's a great resource if you want some *advanced, in-depth* exploration.  Yet I have a feeling you've been there before.

### [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/)

*PS - your analogy between C variable dec/def and JS was spot on.  What you read on Wikipedia was correct.*

Comment: How is it correct? What are the JavaScript semantics for plain `var x;` that are comparable to C or C++?

Comment: The keyword in that statement was 'analogy' meaning they aren't exact matches.  What I said was `correct` is this: `Wikipedia says a declaration allocates memory and the definition assigns a value to this allocated memory.`

Comment: Well my point is that in JavaScript, whether a `var` declaration actually allocates any memory is up to the runtime and pretty much completely transparent.  It's similar to C, but significantly different too.

Comment: Oh ok I gotcha.  Thanks sorry I've been up a really long time lol

Answer (score 14):

Declaring a variable is like telling the (javascript) compiler that this token **`x`** is something I want to use **later**. It does point to a location in memory, but it does not yet contain a value. ie. it is `undefined`

```
var x;
```

defining it means to give it a value which you can either do it like:

```
x = 10; // defining a variable that was declared previously
```

or like this:

```
var y = 20; // declaring and defining a variable altogether.
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67defydd(v=vs.94).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67defydd%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: I guess the location of the object in memory couldn't be retrieved using javascript, (It's C/C++), or at least it would be engine dependent. The size of the object is irrelevant. You are not defining an object, you are declaring one. It only occupies memory when you assign a value to it. Then it is object dependent, ie. is it a number, string or Object.

Answer (score 3):

```
> var x;
undefined
> x
undefined // now it looks like x is defined to the value undefined
> y
ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

Although it is usually said that Javascript is an interpreted language, but there is also a compilation step that happens very fast just before the interpreter runs. The job of this compilation step is to create scope chains, where variables are declared(no read/write operation here, just simple name-keeping) in their respective scopes. These variables will point to some memory location but value in it will be undefined until some execution is carried out by the interpreter.

**> *Compiler run:***

When compiler sees `var x;`, it will simply book-keep this variable in its respective scope.

The next `x;` and `y;` are simply ignored in the compilation step as they are execution statements.

**> *Interpreter run:***

When interpreter sees `var x;`, it will skip this as there is no read/write operation here.

Now when interpreter sees `x;`(execution statement), "x" will already be declared in the scope, and it will hold value "undefined", which is what you get on the console.

But when interpreter sees `y;` similarly, there has been no previous declaration or name-keeping for it in the compilation step, and thus we get the ReferenceError as expected.

*Hope someone finds this comment useful.*

Answer (score 2):

I will give you a long answer for better explanation.

When the javascript engine is not able to find a particular variable in memory, it will throw an error. To be more specific, when the javascript engine (**Execution Context**) is not able to "reference" a variable in memory, it will throw a `ReferenceError`. This is not exactly the same as a **Declaration Error**, at least in javascript.

There is a deference between a `not defined` error and the value `undefined`.

So doing

```
var a = undefined;
```

and

```
var a;
```

will both log the same result i.e. `undefined`. This is because, when you simply do a `var a;` the javascript engine allocates memory for the variable and automatically sets it's value to `undefined`, which is different from saying that `a` doesn't exist at all - in which case it will throw a `ReferenceError`.

### Hoisting

```
console.log(a);    // undefined
var a = 'something';
```

will log `undefined` because, the javascript engine knows there's a variable **declared** somewhere in the code - which means to say that the javascript engine actually does something before it executes the code - one of the thing it does is **hoists** variables. To put it simply, the above code is the same as

```
var a;             // hoisted (declared and defined the value `undefined`)
console.log(a);    // undefined
a = 'something'    // update the defined value to `something`
```

So, yes, declaration and definition happen together in javascript (automatically - if you don't do it yourself) and the default defined value is `undefined`.

### ES6

Just an additional note

```
const a;
```

will throw a `SyntaxError` where a initializer (definition) is necessary. `const` is the only time when you need to declare and define manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x, y, z;

var x;

var h = 4;

i = 4;
```

all the above are global variables if placed at the top, (outside any functions)

Lets say that the javascript has a function start

```
function start() {
      x = 5*5;
}
```

the global variable x is now equal to 25

Where as if the var x; was not placed outside of any functions, that variable x would just be local to that function.

Comment: That does not answer my question. I know the principle of hoisting and the js scoping.

Comment: In strict mode references to undeclared variables is an error.

Answer (score 0):

You declare JavaScript variables with the var keyword:
`var carname;`

After the declaration, the variable is empty (it has no value).

To assign a value to the variable, use the equal sign
`var carname="Volvo";`

In computer programs, variables are often declared without a value. The value can be something that has to be calculated, or something that will be provided later, like user input. Variable declared without a value will have the value undefined.

The variable carname will have the value undefined after the execution of the following statement:
`var carname;`

var hoisting

In JavaScript, a variable can be declared after being used.

```
 bla = 2
 var bla;
  // ...

  // is implicitly understood as:

 var bla;
 bla = 2;
```

For that reason, it is recommended to always declare variable at the top of functions. Otherwise, it may lead to confusing cases

`When declaring a variable without assigning a value to it, there still needs to be some memory available for it, otherwise you cannot make a reference to the variable later in the program. I don't think it's a noticeable amount of memory being used and won't make a difference.`

Answer (score 0):

```
var x;
```

This is a variable declaration. In Js if you don't assign any value to variable in declaration. It will get `undefined` by default.

```
var x; // declaring x
console.log(x); // output: undefined
```

But if you have not even declared the variable in you try to access it. It says that the variable is not defined.

```
console.log(y);  // Output: ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

If you need access to objects between JS files, it's good practice to expose one object to the global namespace and declare fields and methods on that object.

File 1:

```
var myObject;
myObject.myField = "Field!";
```

File 2:

```
myObject.prototype.myFunction = function () {
    return this.myField;
};
```

I have taken from a really good discussion on : [Equivalent of C extern declaration in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151329/equivalent-of-c-extern-declaration-in-javascript)

https://github.com/ganqqwerty/123-Essential-JavaScript-Interview-Questions

Answer (score 0):

Various trivia regarding the difference between undefined and null completely aside, the short answer is: *there is no equivalence in Javascript*.  There are no bare "forward declarations".  *Javascript variable declarations are definitions*.  Variables that have been defined but not explicitly initialized will contain the value 'undefined'.  There is no "external linkage".

If you refer to an identifier that is not in any accessible scope (perhaps because it doesn't exist the first place), you will get your "ReferenceError: y is not defined". This has nothing to do with variable value or storage.

Answer (score -1):

In simple terms,

undefined means **value** to the variable is not defined.

not defined means the **variable** itself is not defined.

`var x;  //value is not defined. So,
 x //undefined`

`//y variable is not declared or defined. So,
 y // y is not defined`

Comment: I think you're confusing undeclared with undefined yourself in this answer on the third line.

Comment: in the third line, since y is not declared and definitely not defined further, it doesn't find a reference to it and so, you get an error that the variable y is not defined.