# var and no var difference in console in javascript

Tags: javascript

If I write in console,

```
var x=0;
```

output=> `undefined`

And If write in console,

```
x=0;
```

output=> `0`

Why so?

Comment: var x = 0 is a declaration and returns undefined(nothing). x=0 is assignment and returns the assigned value

Comment: It is as @Senthilnathan said about declaration and assigment. Check this other question for more info:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822022/javascript-variable-definition-declaration

Comment: To be honest,using `var` depends on your scope, so if both were defined outside any scoped block (like, say, a function), they should both output 0. However, always declare your variables properly using `var` or the new block-scoped `let` or general `const`!

Comment: But when I am writing-   var x=0; that means I am declaring as well as assigning. isn't?

Comment: Yes it is. Read the other question again. (Your question is worded more clearly, but it is asking the same thing.)

Comment: Yes ,You are right @nnnnnn. Previously I went to Bommox link. Sorry

Comment: Well to answer your earlier comment about `var x = 0;` declaring as well as assigning, yes it is. But what the console then displays is the "result" of the `var` *statement*, which is `undefined` in that `var` doesn't return anything. (Whereas the result of the expression `x = 0` *without* the `var` is the value `0`. Which is why statements like `x = y = z = 0` work to assign `0` to all three variables.)

Comment: Thanks man. It was blowing my head