# Angular 2: enum as pipe parameter

Tags: angular

I am trying to use enum as parameter the following way:

```
<div> {{ myValue | myPipe: MyEnum.ENUM_VAL }} </div>
```

In controller I have defined **MyEnum**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
 })
 export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

      MyEnum: MyEnum;

       ....
  }
```

I am getting:  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'ENUM_VAL' of undefined**

What is the proper way of using it?

Comment: First question: Is the `MyEnum` *variable* defined anywhere?

Comment: sure, in MyComponent

Comment: Where? I mean that it should be initialized (inside constructor or ngOnInit) `this.MyEnum = MyEnum.SOMETHING;`, not?

Comment: sorry, you were right :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad that it worked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring MyEnum, but it is not a definition. You would have to initialize it (as @developer033 said).

For reference: [Javascript variable definition declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822022/javascript-variable-definition-declaration)

So give your enum a initial value and it should work, although I have not used an enum in a pipe, you could work around it by placing the enum in your pipe class and sending an argument that tells your pipe to use the enum.