# ngModel is not working while update in tag-Inputs

Tags: angular

Two-way Data binding using ngModel is not working in tag-inputs. Can one please help.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9muqcy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It works fine the array is updated

Comment: Where, no i checked using console. It gives undefined

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: what i am updating in tag-input that i want to show in console. But it gives undefined.

Comment: You console log this.hi

Comment: this.hi is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this:

```
hai(){
console.log(this.hi)
}
```

to this:

```
hai(){
console.log(this.Myarray)
}
```

Check this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czsxvq

Comment: Oh, yes you are right. I am not checking the entire array. just i am checking ngModel value. Anyway thank you.

Comment: From third tag shows in object. I need [Mobiles, Laptops, ThirdTag] like this.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to show `hi` while your ngModel variable is `Myarray`

Answer (score 0):

New Edit -

```
hai(){
   let currItem = this.Myarray[this.Myarray.length-1]['value'];
   this.Myarray.splice(this.Myarray.length-1);
   this.Myarray.push(currItem);
   console.log(this.Myarray)
  }
```

You're getting this error because 'hi' is not defined, it's just declared. This post is a good explanation.

[What's the difference between variable definition and declaration in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822022/whats-the-difference-between-variable-definition-and-declaration-in-javascript)

You need to edit your hai function.

`hai(){
  console.log(this.Myarray)
 }`

Also add this

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, TagInputModule,BrowserAnimationsModule ],
```

Comment: Thank you it is getting but, in array i have already two tags, one is mobiles and another is Laptops. when i entered third tag it gives like this. [mobiles,laptops,Object]. But i need [mobiles,laptops,thirdtag]

Comment: Here i need what i entered all tags need to show. you are showing only length-1, i mean only last tag. Please give a look in the above stackblitz link. On that i have  ["mobiles","laptops"] default. If i entered 'n' number of tags all are need to show in this format--->["mobiles","laptops","x","y","z"...].

Comment: Thanks for Your replies. Finally I got the result.
---->hai(){
 const mynewArr = this.Myarray.map(item => typeof item == "string"? item : item.value)
   console.log(mynewArr)
  }

Comment: The code I wrote should be doing the exact same thing as what you said. It display's all the values of the array in the ["mobiles","laptops","x","y","z"...] format.