# Weird result in console: appends "undefined" to output

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to complete The Odin Project and saw an interesting console error

```js
function repeat(string, number) {
  var finalst;

  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    finalst += string;

  }
  return finalst;
}
console.log(repeat("hey", 3));
```

The result in console is "undefinedheyheyhey". How is it showing like that and why ?

Comment: It's probably because `finalst` is initially set to the value `undefined`. To fix this, set the initial value of `finalst` to an empty string.

Comment: [What's the difference between variable definition and declaration in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822022/whats-the-difference-between-variable-definition-and-declaration-in-javascript#:~:text=What's%20the%20analog%20in%20JS,value%20to%20this%20allocated%20memory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize it like this: `var finalst = "";`:

```js
function repeat(string, number) {
  var finalst = ""; //change this

  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    finalst += string;

  }
  return finalst;
}
console.log(repeat("hey", 3));
```

If you don't, it's initial value will be `undefined`, which will result in `undefined`+`hey`+`hey`+`hey` in your case:

```js
var finalst;
console.log(finalst);
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    finalst += "hey";
}
console.log(finalst);
```

Comment: Instead of only providing code to OP, please also explain _how_ your code has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't init value, it's value = `undefined`.

`finalst += string;`: `finalst.toString()` + `string` => `undefined` + `hey`

You need init `finalst`:

```js
function repeat(string, number) {
  var finalst = "";

  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    finalst += string;

  }
  return finalst;
}
console.log(repeat("hey", 3));
```